# Opera can't open in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, browser, opera

When I'm trying to open Opera it says

> Can't open user profile directory, because you lack sufficient
>   privileges. You might want to contact the administrator of this
>   machine.

What can I do?

Comment: You should explain the case like which error message is shown when you open?

Comment: a pop displaying  "Can't open user profile directory, because you lack sufficient privileges. You might want to contact the administrator of this machine."

Comment: you need to login by your administrator account or give a permission to the normal account that you're logged in.

Comment: Can you describe how you installed opera? The error message sounds like it was installed by root for root, rather than installed for all users.

Comment: @ASIL I've always read it's bad to run as root, and should instead use a regular user's account.

Comment: @plotnik I downloaded opera stable version from official site and installed by dpkg - i file.deb

Comment: It's ok and safe while opening as administrator user, not as a root